# Limit the post title to 60 chars without using a plugin in wordpress

Tags: post, title

Is it possible to display an error When the post title length exceeds 60 chars saying
"You have exceeded the maximum characters allowed X/60".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated my problem to simple question .